# Flex: How to use fade effect on custom ItemRenderer of a List?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, flex3, itemrenderer, effect

Inside my 3.6 Flex module, I am using a List with a custom ItemRenderer:

```
<mx:List id="chatsList" y="0" left="2" right="6" 
    width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{chatsArrayCollection}" 
    horizontalScrollPolicy="off" itemRenderer="MessageRendererModerated" 
    styleName="dataList" variableRowHeight="true" verticalScrollPolicy="auto" >
</mx:List>
```

When I add items to chatsArrayCollection at position 0, I want the list to scroll down and the new item to fade in nicely.
Something similar is shown [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/07/29/setting-an-effect-when-the-items-in-a-data-provider-change-on-a-list-control-in-flex/).

However, this doesn't work for me, and I suspect because I'm using custom itemRenderer.
MessageRendererModerated is defined as a canvas with some text and a link to an image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" minHeight="94" 
    creationComplete="onCreationComplete();" resize="onResize();"  
    scaleY="1" width="100%" 
    horizontalScrollPolicy="off" blendMode="layer" 
    borderStyle="solid" borderThickness="0" 
    xmlns:rtl="views.rtl.*" > ...
```

I have tried different ways to solve this but none helped.

Many thanks!

UPDATE:
Following the comments I got below - I did try to use the itemsChangeEffect as mentioned in the example I found. However, it didn't work as expected.

Comment: You linked to an example where they used the `itemsChangeEffect` to fade in/out the added/removed items - but you don not seem to be using this in your example code. If you tried that, you should show what you did and explain what happened. I suspect it has nothing to do w/your custom renderer :)

Comment: As per sunil you have not mentioned about itemsChangeEffect. Use itemsChangeEffect and add one more property to it that is  startDelay="200 or your value" which may solve your problem.

Comment: Hi Sunil, thanks for responding. As I mentioned, I did try different ways **including** the one mentioned in the linked example (using the `itemsChangeEffect`). I removed that from the original code as it did not work for me. Thx